# Pagination In Javascript Is Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am going to paginate my search page because i have total 16 records in it, So i paginated into 4 pages each comprises of 4 records in each page.I have used javascript to handle pagination.And I have used ajax request in javascript. But My problem is when i click submit button of script.js the first 4 records will display but when i click next button it dosen't display any thing, can u please tell where i went wrong what corrections i need to make, please, 
Thank you in advance.
book_search.php

```
 <?php
    include('assets/page_header.php');

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/page.js">
    </script>


    <div class="container">

    <h1>SEARCHING THE BOOK</h1>

    <form  id="search"  name="search" action="#" method="post">
    Search : <input type="text" name="author" id="author">



    <input id="submit" name="submit"  type="submit" value="Submit">


    <div id="display">


    </div>
    <a href='#' onclick='Next(event)'; >Next</a>
    <a href='#' onclick='Previous(event)'; >Previous</a>
    <a href='#' onclick='Back(event)'; >back</a>
    <a href='#' onclick='LastPage(event)';>LastPage</a>
    <a href="#" onclick='pagination()';>1</a>
    <a href="#" onclick='pagination()';>2</a>
    <a href="#" onclick='pagination()';>3</a>
    <a href="#" onclick='pagination()';>4</a>



    </form>
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
ajax.php

    <?php
    include('db.php');
    $page="";
    if(isset($_GET['page']))
    {

    $page=$_GET['page'];
    echo $page;
    }



    $num_rec_per_page = 5;
    ?>
    <div id="navigation">
    <
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['author']))//&&isset($_POST['page'])&&isset($_POST['total']))
    {


        $author=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['author']);
        $total_pages=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['total']);
        if($author=="")
        {
            echo "Please Enter Title or Author or Publisher";
        }
        else
        {


            if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
            $start_from = ($page-1) * $num_rec_per_page; 

            $query1="select * from books  where  title LIKE '%$author%' OR author LIKE '%$author%' OR publisher LIKE '%$author%'  LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page  ";
            echo $query1;
            $rs_result=mysql_query("select * from books  where  title LIKE '%$author%' OR author LIKE '%$author%' OR publisher LIKE '%$author%'"); 


            $total_records = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);  
            echo $total_records;//count number of records
            $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 
            $phpself=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
            if($page>1)
            {
            $pagenumber=$page-1;
            $prev="<a href=\"$phpself?page=$pagenumber\">[Back]</a>";
            $first="<a href=\"$phpself?page=1\">[FirstPage]</a>";
            }
            else
            {
            $prev='';
            $first='';
            }
            if($page<$total_pages)
            {
            $pagenumber=$page+1;
            $next="<a id='pagin' 'page=$page' >[Next]</a>";
            $last="<a id='pagin' 'total=$total_pages'>[LastPage]</a>";
            }
            else
            {

            $next="";
            $last="";
            /*$next='[next]';
            $last='[LastPage]';*/
            }
            //for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
               // echo "<a href='members1.php?page=".$i."'> ".$i."</a> "; 

          //  };


            echo $first.$prev."Showing page<bold>$page</bold>of<bold>$total_pages</bold>pages".$next.$last;

            /*if($total_records > 0) {
                echo "<a href='members1.php?page=1'> ".'<'." </a> "; // Goto 1st page  
            }
             // echo "<a href='members1.php?page=1'> ".'<<'." </a> ";



            if($total_records > 0) {
                echo "<a href='members1.php?page=$total_pages'> ".'>'." </a> "; // Goto last page
            }*/


            $result1=mysql_query($query1) or  die(mysql_error());
            //print_r($result1);
            $count=mysql_num_rows($result1);
            //echo $count;
            $display= "<table align='center'>";
            $display.= "<tr><td>title</td>   <td>author</td>   <td>publisher</td>   <td>numcopies</td>    <td>status</td>    <td>number_of_copies_available</td> <td>Action</td> </tr>";
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
                $count=mysql_num_rows($result1);
                //print_r($row['bookid']);
                $r12=$row['bookid'];
                $query2=mysql_query("select bookid from bookrentalinfo where bookid=$r12");
                $num_copies_borrowed=mysql_num_rows($query2);   
                $num_copies_count=$row['numcopies'];
                $number_of_copies_available=$num_copies_count-$num_copies_borrowed;
                $display.= "<tr>";
                //echo "<td>".$row['bookid']."</td>";
            $display.="<td>".$row['title']."</td>";
                $display.= "<td>".$row['author']."</td>";
                $display.= "<td>".$row['publisher']."</td>";
                $display.= "<td>".$row['numcopies']."</td>";        
                $display.= "<td>".$row['status']."</td>";   
                $display.= "<td>".$number_of_copies_available."</td>";
                if($number_of_copies_available>0)
                {
                    $display.= "<td><a href='borrow_search.php?book_id=".$row['bookid']."'>Rent</a></td>";      
                }
                else {
                    $display.= "rent link is not activated";
                    $display.="<td></td>";      
                }

                $display.= "</tr>";
            }
            $display.="</table>";
            echo $display;

        }
    }
    ?>

        </div>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['start'])&& isset($_POST['end'])&&isset($_POST['author']))
        {
        echo "hi";


        $author=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['author']);

        $start_val=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['start']);
        $end_val=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['end']);
        $start_val=$page;
        $end_val=$start_val*5;


        $string=" select * from books  where  title LIKE '%$author%' OR author LIKE '%$author%' OR publisher LIKE '%$author%'  LIMIT $start_val, $end_val  ";
        echo $string;
        $query20=mysql_query($string);
        echo $query20;

        $display= "<table align='center'>";
            $display.= "<tr><td>title</td>   <td>author</td>   <td>publisher</td>   <td>numcopies</td>    <td>status</td>    <td>number_of_copies_available</td> <td>Action</td> </tr>";
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query20)){
                $count=mysql_num_rows($query20);
                //print_r($row['bookid']);
                $r12=$row['bookid'];
                $query2=mysql_query("select bookid from bookrentalinfo where bookid=$r12");
                $num_copies_borrowed=mysql_num_rows($query2);   
                $num_copies_count=$row['numcopies'];
                $number_of_copies_available=$num_copies_count-$num_copies_borrowed;
                $display.= "<tr>";
                //echo "<td>".$row['bookid']."</td>";
            $display.="<td>".$row['title']."</td>";
                $display.= "<td>".$row['author']."</td>";
                $display.= "<td>".$row['publisher']."</td>";
                $display.= "<td>".$row['numcopies']."</td>";        
                $display.= "<td>".$row['status']."</td>";   
                $display.= "<td>".$number_of_copies_available."</td>";
                if($number_of_copies_available>0)
                {
                    $display.= "<td><a href='borrow_search.php?book_id=".$row['bookid']."'>Rent</a></td>";      
                }
                else {
                    $display.= "rent link is not activated";
                    $display.="<td></td>";      
                }

                $display.= "</tr>";
            }
            $display.="</table>";
            echo $display;

        }

        ?>
page.js

var no_of_records=16;
    var items_per_page=4;
    var page=1;
    var start_page=1;
    var end_page=0;


    function Next(e)
    {
    var start_page=page;
    var end_page=start_page*5;
    var TotalPages=Math.ceil(no_of_records/items_per_page);
    page++;
    e.preventDefault();


    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "db/ajax.php",
            data: {'start':start_page,'end':end_page,'page':page},
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
            //alert("submitted"+result);
            $('#display').html(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
            }



        });
        }



    function pagination()
                {

                    e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "db/ajax.php",
                    data: {'start':start_page,'end':end_page,'page':page},
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(result){
                    //alert("submitted"+result);
                    $('#display').html(result);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            alert(xhr.status);
                            alert(thrownError);
                    }



                });

                }
                function Previous(e)
            {
            var start_page=page;
            var end_page=start_page*5;
            var TotalPages=Math.ceil(no_of_records/items_per_page);
            page--;
            e.preventDefault();


            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "db/ajax.php",
                    data: {'start':start_page,'end':end_page,'page':page},
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(result){
                    //alert("submitted"+result);
                    $('#display').html(result);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            alert(xhr.status);
                            alert(thrownError);
                    }



                });
                }

script.js

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(e){
    var author = $("#author").val();





        var dataString='author='+author;
        alert(dataString);


            if(author=='')
            {
            alert("Please Enter Author or Title or Publisher Fields");
            }
            else
            {
                // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "db/ajax.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                //alert("submitted"+result);
                $('#display').html(result);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(xhr.status);
                        alert(thrownError);
                }
                });
            }
            e.preventDefault(); 
            });
    });
```

Comment: check your console on `next button click` see what it throws

Comment: I won't find any error

Comment: put a breakpoints on next button click and check did it fire or not?

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple way of pagination according to the class name:

```
    var totalPages;
function updatePagination(page) {
    $(".pagination").html("");
    for (var i = page-1; i < page + 3; i++) {
        $('.pagination').append("<li onclick=displayPage("+(i+1)+"); class='current-page'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>" + (i+1) + "</a></li>&nbsp;");
    }
}
var limitPerPage=25;
function displayPage(currentPage){
        if(currentPage==totalPages) return false;
        updatePagination(currentPage);
      // Check if page number that was clicked on is the current page that is being displayed
    //   if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    //     return false; // Return false (i.e., nothing to do, since user clicked on the page number that is already being displayed)
    //   } else {
        //var currentPage = $(this).index();
        //updatePagination(currentPage);
         // Get the current page number
        $(".pagination li").removeClass('active'); // Remove the 'active' class status from the page that is currently being displayed
        $(this).addClass('active'); // Add the 'active' class status to the page that was clicked on
        $("#cardsdisplay .ma-card").hide(); // Hide all items in loop, this case, all the list groups
        var grandTotal = limitPerPage * currentPage; // Get the total number of items up to the page number that was clicked on
    
        // Loop through total items, selecting a new set of items based on page number
        for (var i = grandTotal - limitPerPage; i < grandTotal; i++) {
          $("#cardsdisplay .ma-card:eq(" + i + ")").show(); // Show items from the new page that was selected
        }
     // }
    
}


function PaginateVideos(){
    'use strict';
    console.log("inisde pagination");
    var numberOfItems = $('#cardsdisplay .ma-card').length; // Get total number of the items that should be paginated
    console.log(numberOfItems);
    var limitPerPage = 25; // Limit of items per each page
    $('#cardsdisplay .ma-card:gt(' + (limitPerPage - 1) + ')').hide(); // Hide all items over page limits (e.g., 5th item, 6th item, etc.)
    totalPages = Math.round(numberOfItems / limitPerPage); // Get number of pages
    //$(".pagination").append("<li class='current-page active'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>" + 1 + "</a></li>&nbsp;"); // Add first page marker
    
    // Loop to insert page number for each sets of items equal to page limit (e.g., limit of 4 with 20 total items = insert 5 pages)
    for (var i = 0; i <3; i++) {
      $(".pagination").append("<li onclick=displayPage("+(i+1)+"); class='current-page'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>" + (i+1) + "</a></li>&nbsp;"); // Insert page number into pagination tabs
    }
    
    // Add next button after all the page numbers  
    $(".pagination").append("<li id='next-page'><a href='javascript:void(0)' aria-label=Next><span aria-hidden=true>&raquo;</span></a></li>");
    
    // Function that displays new items based on page number that was clicked
    // $(".pagination li.current-page").on("click", function() {
    
    // });
    
    // Function to navigate to the next page when users click on the next-page id (next page button)
    $("#next-page").on("click", function() {
      var currentPage = $(".pagination li.active").index(); // Identify the current active page
      // Check to make sure that navigating to the next page will not exceed the total number of pages
      if (currentPage === totalPages) {
        return false; // Return false (i.e., cannot navigate any further, since it would exceed the maximum number of pages)
      } else {
        currentPage++; // Increment the page by one
        $(".pagination li").removeClass('active'); // Remove the 'active' class status from the current page
        $("#cardsdisplay .ma-card").hide(); // Hide all items in the pagination loop
        var grandTotal = limitPerPage * currentPage; // Get the total number of items up to the page that was selected
    
        // Loop through total items, selecting a new set of items based on page number
        for (var i = grandTotal - limitPerPage; i < grandTotal; i++) {
          $("#cardsdisplay .ma-card:eq(" + i + ")").show(); // Show items from the new page that was selected
        }
    
        $(".pagination li.current-page:eq(" + (currentPage - 1) + ")").addClass('active'); // Make new page number the 'active' page
      }
    });
    
    // Function to navigate to the previous page when users click on the previous-page id (previous page button)
    $("#previous-page").on("click", function() {
      var currentPage = $(".pagination li.active").index(); // Identify the current active page
      // Check to make sure that users is not on page 1 and attempting to navigating to a previous page
      if (currentPage === 1) {
        return false; // Return false (i.e., cannot navigate to a previous page because the current page is page 1)
      } else {
        currentPage--; // Decrement page by one
        $(".pagination li").removeClass('active'); // Remove the 'activate' status class from the previous active page number
        $("#cardsdisplay .ma-card").hide(); // Hide all items in the pagination loop
        var grandTotal = limitPerPage * currentPage; // Get the total number of items up to the page that was selected
    
        // Loop through total items, selecting a new set of items based on page number
        for (var i = grandTotal - limitPerPage; i < grandTotal; i++) {
          $("#cardsdisplay .ma-card:eq(" + i + ")").show(); // Show items from the new page that was selected
        }
    
        $(".pagination li.current-page:eq(" + (currentPage - 1) + ")").addClass('active'); // Make new page number the 'active' page
      }
    });

}
```

`UpdatePagination()` is only if you had huge number of pages, so you can control the display